# OnChange() does not fire in JQuery UI buttonset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery Buttonset on an aspx page. I've been running the page successfully on my local machine. The alarmChanged()-method is called when I select one of the two options. When I deployed it to a win2008 server, the onchange is not fired anymore. The markup looks like this:

```
<td id="ButtonSetMenu" class="buttonSet">
  <div id="AlarmTypeOptions" > 
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="H" value="1" name="radio" onchange="alarmChanged()"/>
      <label for="H">
        <span id="H" style='background: transparent'">H</span>
        <span style="background:transparent;"> 3</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="L" value="2" name="radio" onchange="alarmChanged()"/>
      <label for="L">
        <span id="L" style='background: transparent'">L</span>
        <span style="background:transparent;"> 3</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>  
</td>
```

Any ideas on what that could be causing this?

Comment: What are the errors appearing in your `console log` ?

Comment: Have you tried listening for the change events using jQuery?

Comment: Actually it works in Firefox, but not in IE8. But when hosting it locally it worked fine in IE8 as well.

Comment: The problem was that one of the spans used the same id as the input

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.change()` event

```
$('#AlarmTypeOptions :radio').change(function () {
    // do something
    alert($('#AlarmTypeOptions :radio:checked').val());
});
```